# AS import in Flash project in Flash Builder

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, import, movieclip, builder

So I'm trying to make a 3 tier flash application where the main.as calles all the movieclips and addChild()'s them. those movieclip classes are situated in the com.ui package but somehow my app can't load them, they only load is I move my movieclip classes to the default package (the root folder).

How can I import those movieclips like this -> import com.ui.myMovieClip;

I'm using Flash CS5 and Flash Builder

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder with the following structure, whereas , folder contains the com folder that contains the ui folder etc...

```
/folder 
   / com
     / ui
       /your classes
```

In FlashBuilder , set folder as a SourcePath for your project. In your classes tree on the left you should see the com folder in one of the source paths.

Each class contained in  the ui folder will be in a package such as

```
package com.ui
{
   //etc
}
```

Comment: I have this but I also have a main class in the root of my project that calls all of those classes in UI but that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: @zendy do you need to add the folder to the class path? File > Publish Settings... > Flash (tab) > ActionScript version: Settings...

Comment: can you tell us what you're using FlashBuilder & Flash CS5 for. What I mean , is where do you edit your Main Class , what do you use Flash CS for, graphic assets with linkage?

Comment: Flash builder to edit and organise actionscript classes, flash cs5 for visual creations like movieclips and such with linkage